# How To Use Sockets in my Xamarin.Forms App?

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin

I've been searching for some ideas of how using Sockets in My XamarinForms App , I only found some tutorials for Android Studio which gave me some ideas , but I'd like to check more specific Links .

If anyone can provide me some links that can help me , I'll be so thankful



Comment: I would suggest trying some of the links you have found and taking a look at the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823404/server-client-application-with-net-and-xamarin as your question might get closed due to it not being specific about programming but rather looking for links

Comment: Are you considering using `WebSocket`?https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/developing-real-time-communication-apps-with-websocket/

Comment: Update , I finally could connect create a little program to test Server/Client Sockets . I made a console app as a server , and the client on my emulator , and It works
the problem is that when I use the app on my physical phone , it doesn't work , I even changed the IP address on my client program to match the one I have on my phone , but Im not able to connect .

Comment: @KhalidHarkati Hi, If solved this question, remember to mark it :).From your new question, you can create a new question with detail info in SO.It will he helpful to solve the new question.